Key-value “sub-parameter” with Python’s argparse
I want to make the --new-entry parameter be able to process a key-value sequence with space as statement separator.
As example:
script.py --new-entry name="The Republic" author="Plato" year="-400"

In this example, name="The Republic" author="Plato" year="-400" is the whole value of the parameter --new-entry. Ideally, I want to get it inside a dictionary, like:
    {
        "name": "The Republic",
        "author": "Plato",
        …
    }

What I didn’t search to do
Instead of what some people are searching elsewhere, I am not trying to make multiple parameters to get the different values. All the needed variables (name, author, year) should be retrieved inside one paramet
The question
So, is their a feature like this inside argparse, or with any other library?

This question is similar to: parsing arguments as a dictionary argparse. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Wouldn't it be easier (and more like what people expect) to just invoke the script multiple times?  Whatever you come up with is going to be a hack.  Simplicity is a noble goal.

Define a --new-entry optionalto take multople values (withnargs).  Then after parsing look at the args.new_entrylist of strings.  Split each on '=' and make your dict from that.argparse` does not handle 'key=value' pairs.  You have to do that yourself.

@hpaulj verry usefull. I find a path like this. I will improve my code and bring a solution later.

Here is one way to do it: by create a custom action.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import contextlib
import json


class JsonKeyValueAction(argparse.Action):
    """
    Parses command-line key=value pairs, then attempt to JSON decode the values
    """

    @staticmethod
    def _parse_key_value(key_value):
        key, value = key_value.split("=", 1)
        with contextlib.suppress(json.decoder.JSONDecodeError):
            value = json.loads(value)
        return key, value

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        dict_object = getattr(namespace, self.dest) or {}
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, dict_object)
        dict_object.update(self._parse_key_value(kv) for kv in values)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "-n", "--new-entry", nargs="*", action=JsonKeyValueAction, default={}
    )
    options = parser.parse_args()
    print(options.new_entry)

Sample invocation:
$ ./script.py --new-entry name="The Republic" author="Plato" year="-400"
{'name': 'The Republic', 'author': 'Plato', 'year': -400}

Notes

The method _parse_key_value will parse such text as 'name="The Republic"' and return ('name', 'The Republic'). Note that it uses the json.loads() function to parse the value. Which means it can parse string, integer, boolean, list, dictionary, ... Things which json can parse.
The first two lines in the __call__() method ensure that the attribute new_entry is defined (if not, then define it).

